# Scala: recursive value listHuman needs type

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming

Why is this function giving me the following error:

> recursive value listHuman needs type

```
def setHumanResources(physicalResources: List[Physical], totalHumanResources: List[Human]): List[Human] = {
    val listHuman = physicalResources.map{pr => totalHumanResources.find(_.handles.contains(pr.post)).filterNot(a=>listHuman.contains(a))}
    return listHuman
}
```

I tried to do this, but it gives me another error:

```
val listHuman: List[Human] = physicalResources.map{pr => totalHumanResources.find(_.handles.contains(pr.post)).get}.filterNot(human=>listHuman.contains(human))
```

> forward reference extends over definition of value listHuman

Comment: the `listHuman` value definition is referring itself @ `filterNot(human=>listHuman.contains(human)`. is that expected?

Comment: Yes, I want listHuman not to have repeated elements. This was my approach. I don't know if it is correct or not, but was what I was trying to test.

Comment: can you post the class definition of the `Human` and what fields must be considered for equality?

Comment: Unrelated, but there is no need to have `return` in scala code. The last value of the function will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that constant value or variable is used before its declaration. For example

```
    val y = x + 2
    val x = 5
```

What wrong with your code is you try to define constant value with itself. It's impossible by definition of `constant`. To build recursion use `def`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to do a `foldLeft`, does this work?

```
def setHumanResources(physicalResources: List[Physical], totalHumanResources: List[Human]): List[Human] = {
  physicalResources.foldLeft(Set.empty[Human]) { (l, pr) =>
    val applicableHuman = totalHumanResources.find(_.handles.contains(pr.post))
    l ++ applicableHuman
  }.toList
}
```

Comment: For what I understood, your code ignores the duplicates right? That's not just what I want. I want the function to ignore the duplicate, but to find the next "applicableHuman" in the `totalHumanResources` list.

Comment: Both those assumptions are correct: duplicates are eliminated by using a Set type, so if totalHumanResources contain any duplicates, we will ensure they are not added to the end result of the method. All the applicableHumans are congregated to the final Set, which is then converted to a List. Here's a good source on foldLeft: https://oldfashionedsoftware.com/2009/07/10/scala-code-review-foldleft-and-foldright/

Answer (score 0):

The premises here is to have `setHumanResources`return a unique/distint list of `Human` objects. The code tries this by doing `filterNot(a=>listHuman.contains(a))` in definition of `listHuman` and thus recursively referring to `listHuman` while defining `listHuman` in semantically illegal way. This de-duping can be achieved properly by the following ways.

- convert the List to Set and convert it back to List to remove duplicates like  `listHuman.toSet.ToList`. for this method to work the Human object have property identity defined by overriding `equals` method. so the code will now look like

  ```
  def setHumanResources(physicalResources: List[Physical], totalHumanResources: List[Human]): List[Human] = {
        val listHuman = physicalResources.map{pr => totalHumanResources.find(_.handles.contains(pr.post))
        listHuman.toSet.toList
  }
  ```

  A Demo for a sample class of Human is shown below.

  ```
   scala> class Human(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) {
   |   override def toString = this.firstName
   |   override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = that match {
   |      case that: Human if that.firstName == this.firstName => true
   |      case _ => false
   |   }
   | }
  defined class Human

  scala> List(new Human("Peter", "Parker"), new Human("Peter", "Quill")).toSet.toList
  res14: List[Human] = List(Peter)
  ```
- If the class `Human` cannot have object equality defined in it by overriding equals method then follow this approach. considering each `Human` can be uniquely identified by say two properties `property1` and `property2`. the listHuman can be deduped by the following expression. For our previously defined `Human` class if we want to de-dupe on both firstName and lastName properties, the code would be like below.

  ```
  listHuman.groupBy(x => (x.firstName, x.lastName)).map(_._2.head)
  ```

  so the new method definition becomes

  ```
    def setHumanResources(physicalResources: List[Physical], totalHumanResources: List[Human]): List[Human] = {
         val listHuman = physicalResources.map{pr => 
         totalHumanResources.find(_.handles.contains(pr.post))
         listHuman.groupBy(x => (x.property1, x.property2) ).map(_._2.head)
     }
  ```